How to create Multiple Nested Table in RDLC Report using multiple DataSets?
I have four dataSets, ConfRegistrations, RegDetails, RegSubDetails, and Members. I want to create a table for ConfRegistration and want to create a sub-table to show the RegDetails based on ConfRegId inside the table below each row if there any details available based on ConfRegId, I want to make another sub-table inside the first sub-table (regDetails) for RegSubDetails based on RegDetailId. I have tried multiple ways, but I think I am missing something, but I couldn't figure out the solution.
another thing, in our old ERP (.NET core 9) has thousands of rdlc reports, maximum list report's header, footer, and table headers are Repeated into the each new page, but I can see there are no repeatable configurations for the  Table header, therefore it repeat properly. but in the same process couldn't work in my new project report! I don't know why, is there any configuration to set the table header for repeat on each new page?
